# Error while compiling Qt with Phonon

Tags: networking, qt, phonon

I have this problem. I have a code line:

```
[  **QT += declarative network phonon**  ]
```

Which says:

```
[  ***:-1: error: Unknown module(s) in QT: phonon***  ]
```

after compiling.

I have tried to install Phonon packages and they don't help at all.
I have newest version of QT.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `multimediawidgets` to your QT variable in your project file:

```
QT += multimediawidgets
```

Note that Phonon no longer exists in Qt 5. Use the Multimedia module instead